# PHP - Run JavaScript if a file exists

Tags: javascript, php

I have a text file which I'm outputting to my server from my phone and I also have an index.php page which I load onto my browser.  I also have a JavaScript function in a separate JS file.  I'd like to call this JavaScript function if the text file appears on my server.  What code can I add into my PHP page to accomplish this?

Forgive me if this seems primitive but I am pretty new to PHP and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
 $script = <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
EOD;
echo file_exists("/path/to/that/file") ? $script : "nothing";
?>
```

Comment: perfect, thank you!